# Taking a screenshot and sending it without saving in mobile device memory

Tags: java, android, screenshot

Is there a way to take a screenshot and send it (e.g. via mail programm) **without** saving a file in mobile device memory (internal/external)? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is to vague to answer correctly, but probably the answer you will get after specifying is "no".

Android's interprocess communication relies on passing "small" data as in-memory structures and "big" data as file descriptors. Unless you own all the actor-processes (app that takes a screenshot, app that passes it to the email client and the email client) you cannot change that.